# How do you update an array in localStorage without overwriting same-key values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am trying to retrieve an arrray from local storage, append a new array with the same keys, then stick it back into storage. I can't seem to get it to work however, I've tried turning my arrays into object, and objects into arrays (I'm new to programming so I'm not sure what the best way is.) I've also tried using the spread operator, object.entries(), object.assign() and  a few other nonsensical options.

EDIT:

Saved to storage are the user input values:
`"[[["name","bob ross"],["about","Painter"]]]"`

I want the user to be able to add "Bilbo Baggins" for name, and "Hobbit" for about, then the storage should look like:

`"[[["name","bob ross"],["about","Painter"]]], [[["name","Bilbo Baggins"],["about","Hobbit"]]]"`

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's my code:

```
//============= Allows writing to LocalStorage without overwrite ==========================
submitbtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const oldInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));  // Retrieves info from storage to make it writeable
    console.log('old Info: ', oldInfo); // Shows user what's currently saved in oldInfo
    const newInfo = {};
            newInfo.name = name.value; // Name and about are user input values
            newInfo.about = about.value;
    let array = Object.entries(newInfo); // Turns newInfo into an array
    console.log('new info: ', newInfo);
    oldInfo.push(array); // Appends newInfo to oldInfo without overwriting oldInfo data
    console.log(oldInfo);
    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(oldInfo)); // Saves newly updated array to localStorage
});
```

Comment: It's unclear what you expect to happen, exactly?

Can you add an example to your question, with the state of the storage, before, what the new info is, and what you expect to be in storage, afterwards? (So, just plain data, what do you need to happen?)

Comment: In the question, @TraktorJack.

Comment: No problem.

Ehm, as far as I can see, your code should be doing _exactly_ what you want already... Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: No, It's just not appending the new values. It simply overwrites them

Comment: The expected output should have double brackets "inside", not triple, `"[[["name","bob ross"],["about","Painter"]], [["name","Bilbo Baggins"],["about","Hobbit"]]]"`. Are you aware of that JSON can store objects too, not just lists? It could be `[{"name":"Bob Ross","about":"Painter"},{"name":"Bilbo Baggins","about":"Hobbit"}]`

Comment: @tevemadar Is there any benefit other than readability?

Comment: You can access the fileds by name afterwards. Right now there is a list of name-value pairs, for finding the name of Bilbo Baggins, one would have to loop over the list of lists, and check if the first element is "name", and if it is, then get the actual name from the second element, "Bilbo Baggins". Like `function getName(listOfLists){for(let list of listOfLists)if(list[0]==="name")return list[1];}` would be `function getName(obj){return obj.name;}`. The storage could also be `oldInfo.push({name:name.value,about:about.value});` instead of the `Object.entries()` magic

Comment: So yes, people do use objects sometimes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've cleaned up the code a little.

Your code should work, except that is was missing some error handling for the first load.

```js
// Mock data
const name = { value: 'Foo name' };
const about = { value: 'Bar about' };
const submitbtn = document.getElementById('submit');

// Fake localStorage to make it work in the snippet
mockLocalStorage = {
  getItem: (key) => this[key],
  setItem: (key, value) => this[key] = value
};

submitbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Make sure we get -something- back in case this is the first time we're accessing the storage.
  const oldInfo = JSON.parse(mockLocalStorage.getItem('data') || '[]');
  console.log('Before', oldInfo);

  // The creation of the new object can be done in 1 step.  
  const array = Object.entries({
    name: name.value,
    about: about.value
  });

  oldInfo.push(array); // Appends newInfo to oldInfo without overwriting oldInfo data
  console.log('After', oldInfo);
  mockLocalStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(oldInfo));
});
```

```html
<button id="submit" type="button">Submit!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to keep an object format, as you seems to only need to update properties, and not store.

That way, you can simply update your store by using your oldInfo object and using spread operator to create a new object from it (and get rid of conversion):

Let's say you put this in your localStorage (stringified):

```
const initialInfo = {
   name: '',
   about: ''
};
```

Then you can simply do

```
const oldInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
localStorage.setItem(
   'data',
   JSON.stringify({ ...oldInfo, name: name.value, about: about.value })
);
```

This `...` are syntaxic sugar for Object.assign, and to my mind, helps a lot to read instruction.
Here it means that you are 'cloning' the oldInfo object, and assigning new values to listed properties placed behind it.

EDIT:

After question editing; if you want to store multiple objects within an array, you should go with array spread operator. Like so:

```
const oldInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
// oldInfo = [{ name: 'example', about: 'test' }];

const yourNewObject = {
   value: name.value,
   about: about.value
};
localStorage.setItem(
   'data',
   JSON.stringify([ ...oldInfo, yourNewObject ])
);
```

This way you will add an object to your array

Comment: No, looking at the edit, the OP wants to _add_ entries, not replace them

Comment: thanks, I wrote the answer without seeing the edit that came during my typing :)

Comment: Thanks @Alex! Cerbrus' answer was more tailored to what I needed, but thank you for your help :)